# Is it allowed to use short or any other types in place of int in bit fileds

Tags: c, bit-fields

In most of the example I have seen about bit fields
`unsigned int` is used.

```
struct example
{
    unsigned int number: 1
}
```

why can't we use `unsigned short` or some  other data type instead?

Comment: Who says you can't?

Comment: Once you've exactly specified the number of bits, it would be kind of strange to call it `long` or `short`.  There's default `int`, and then as a departure from that there's `short int` and `long int`, and then as a totally different departure there's bitfields which are exact-sized ints, but it doesn't really make sense to apply both departures at once.

Comment: Remember that bit-fields are weird, not least because most aspects of their behaviour are implementation defined.  One particular issue is that using plain `int` may create a signed or an unsigned bit-field — one of many aspects of implementation-defined behaviour.  Note that the implementation must specify what it does, but it may do either.  Anywhere else, `int` is equivalent to `signed int`.

Answer (score 3):

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field):

> Bit fields can have only one of four types (possibly `const` or `volatile` qualified):
>
> - `unsigned int`, for unsigned bit fields (`unsigned int b:3;` has the range 0..7)
> - `signed int`, for signed bit fields (`signed int b:3;` has the range -4..3)
> - `int`, for bit fields with implementation-defined signedness (Note that this differs from the meaning of the keyword int everywhere else, where it means "signed int"). For example, `int b:3;` may have the range of values 0..7 or -4..3.
> - `_Bool`, for single-bit bit fields (`bool x:1;` has the range 0..1 and implicit conversions to and from it follow the boolean conversion rules.
>
> Additional implementation-defined types may be acceptable.

It helps somewhat to think of this in analogous terms to how you have (outside of bitfields) `unsigned char`, `signed char`, and `char` (with the latter's signed-ness being implementation defined).

Comment: bitfield is the definition of implemented defined as `i = i++` the definition of undefined behavior.

Comment: @Stargateur: Would you mind editing / rephrasing that comment, as I have no idea what you wanted to say there?

Comment: @DevSolar I think he's trying to say that bitfield specifics are the canonical example of implementation-defined behavior.  (They're not just a random example of implementation-defined behavior, he thinks they're the first thing anyone thinks of when they think of implementation-defined behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

Section 6.7.2.1p5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) dictates the types that are allowed for a bit-field:

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified
>   version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, **or some other
>   implementation-defined type**. It is implementation-defined whether
>   atomic types are permitted.

So a standard-conforming compiler *may* support `unsigned short` as a type for a bit-field, but it doesn't have to.  So yes, you *can* use `unsigned short` for a bit-field if the implementation allows it.

For example, [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html) does support it:

> **4.9 Structures, Unions, Enumerations, and Bit-Fields**
>
> ...
>
> - *Allowable bit-field types other than _Bool, signed int, and unsigned
>     int (C99 and C11 6.7.2.1).*
>
>   Other integer types, such as long int, and enumerated types are
>     permitted even in strictly conforming mode.

As does [MCVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx):

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> declarator  : constant-expression
> ```
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The (optional) declarator is the name by which the member is accessed
>   in the program. **It must be an integral type (including enumerated
>   types).** The constant-expression specifies the number of bits the
>   member occupies in the structure. Anonymous bit fields — that is,
>   bit-field members with no identifier — can be used for padding.

Implementations that use integer types besides `int` can use that size to determine how much padding to use between bit-fields and other fields.

Comment: Yea... standard trumps cppreference.cpp. FWIW, I brought this up on the discussion page over there.

Comment: @DevSolar I believe `signed int` is equivalent to `int`.  On the other hand, it is implementation defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: @DevSolar : cppreference isn't wrong about `int` having implementation defined signed-ness in the context of a bit-field. Ref. 6.7.2§5 : "Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except that for bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`."

Comment: In a bit-field, I believe `signed int` is not necessarily equivalent to `int` — though that equivalence applies everywhere else.